# how to update a variable in ui.R using observer in server.R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a variable that is declared in ui.R

```
cond1 <- 0
```

If certain conditions are met in server.R, I want to update

```
cond1 <- 1
```

I tried the following in server.R

```
observer({
###if certain conditions are met, update value of cond1
updateTextInput(session,"cond1",value=1)})
```

The idea is to have an if statement

```
if(cond1==1){
#display panel in ui.R}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this is probably the wrong way to approach it. The point of ui and server if that UI contains only interface stuff and server contains the logic. You shouldn't really be declaring and modifying variables in the ui.  It's possible that what you're trying to do is doable with `conditionalPanel()`, look at that function

Answer (score 2):

You can do `conditionalPanels`, use `renderUI` or use jQuery, here's a example of all of them:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      tags$head(
        tags$script(
          HTML(
            '
            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("toggleUI",function(message){
              if( message.show ){
                $("#"+message.selector).show();
              }
              else{
                $("#"+message.selector).hide();
              }
            })
            '
          )
        )
      ),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("selection","Select UI",choices = c("ui1"="ui1","ui2"="ui2","ui3"="ui3"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          uiOutput("ui1"),
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.selection == 'ui2'",
            sliderInput("breakCount", "Break Count", min=1, max=1000, value=10)
          ),
          fluidRow( id="ui3",
                    div("Some more here")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
    observeEvent(input$selection,{
      # Get selected value
      sel.val <- input$selection

      # If selection = ui1
      if (sel.val == 'ui1'){
        output$ui1 <- renderUI({
          plotOutput('plt')
        })
        output$plt <- renderPlot({plot(runif(100))})
      } else{
        # Remove ui1
        output$ui1 <- renderUI({ NULL})
      }

      # Toggle ui3
      if (sel.val == 'ui3'){
        session$sendCustomMessage(type='toggleUI', message=list(selector='ui3',show=TRUE))
      } else{
        session$sendCustomMessage(type='toggleUI', message=list(selector='ui3',show=FALSE))
      }
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: Hi Oskar, I hope you are doing well. I have a new question that maybe I thought you could help with. I greatly appreciate your help and your time. Thanks.